# The usage of "but" in a sentence

Tags: adverbial-phrases

Please take a look at this passage:

> It is due to a misunderstanding that most modern sculptures are
> monochromatic. When ancient sculptures were exhumed years ago, they
> were discovered to be uncolored. No one at that time had reason to
> believe, as we now do, that the sculptures had originally been
> colorfully painted, *but* that centuries of exposure to moisture washed
> away the paint.

I can't tell exactly what's the usage of "but" in the last part of the passage. When seeing it as a conjunction, it seems wrong because it should not be preceded by a comma. This is as far as I could go.

So, then, is it an adverbial clause "but + noun clause" meaning "only"? Also, what does the second sentence really mean?

I would really appreciate any helps!

Comment: The comma is optional, but personally I would omit it. The last part is a coordination construction consisting of two declarative content clauses, the second one introduced by the coordinator "but":  "[that the sculptures had originally been colorfully painted], but [that centuries of exposure to moisture washed away the paint]", where the bracketed clauses form the coordinates. "But" introduces a clause whose content contrasts with what is said in the first coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is rather long and convoluted. It means:

> The sculptures had originally been painted. Over the centuries they were exposed to moisture, which washed away the paint. When they were first discovered no-one had any reason to believe this had happened. These days we do have reason to believe it.

The "but" is being used as a conjunction in the clause

> the sculptures had originally been painted but sentences of exposure to moisture washed away the paint

and as you say a preceding comma is not really correct in this situation. The author inserted it as a "pause-for-breath comma" because the sentence had gotten too long. I also think the author's use of the construction "believe that... but that..." is not correct; they should have used "believe that... but..." instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, randomhead! But, why the but is not an adverbial clause?

Comment: @Lenny you could read it that way too: *The sculptures were painted, **only** the paint had been washed away.**